# How to populate dropdown with database using Jquery Tabledit Plugin with Php Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, database

I have found a plugin for an inline editable table with a dropdown, however I want to populate the dropdown with values from database. The code I have have a dropdown only for 'gender' with 2 values.
I have found the following code which I am trying to adapt, but unfortunately not lucky. I tried to create a query and use a php variable but wasn't working. It's my first time using a Jquery plugin, and I was surprise to find out that is not easy to find tables with dropdowns, and the ones available are normally with fixed values. It's a pitty because they can be so useful. I am so tired of trying to figure this out, any help I would really appreciate!

The Table:
[Inline editable Table with dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEGia.png)

The code is the following :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
var dataTable = $('#sample_data').DataTable({
"processing" : true,
"serverSide" : true,
  "order" : [],
"ajax" : {
url:"fetch.php",
type:"POST"
}
});


$('#sample_data').on('draw.dt', function(){
 $('#sample_data').Tabledit({
 url:'action.php',
 dataType:'json',
 columns:{
identifier : [0, 'id'],
editable:[[1, 'first_name'], [2, 'last_name'], [3, 'gender', '{"1":"Male","2":"Female"}']]
 },
restoreButton:false,
 onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
 {
 if(data.action == 'delete')
{
$('#' + data.id).remove();
$('#sample_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();
}
}
 });
 });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know which version of jQuery you are using.

Comment: I use 3.4.1 so should be able to help but I think there may be an issue with the PHP. Are you saying you're unable to populate the table with data?

Comment: The datable is working correctly. I was just trying to adapt this table in order to have a dynamic dropdown as the rest of the columns. Only the dropdown list field have fixed values: [3, 'gender', '{"1":"Male","2":"Female"}'] However, I am not sure how to replace these with database values since I am not very familiar with jquery, ajax and json, so I have been making some research and studying a bit, but unfortunately I am still not able to figure this out.

Comment: You could add those extra columns to the table and then hide them using CSS. Then have a button which shows a simple menu of what extra columns are available. If someone selects a new column, show(); it using jQuery. What you'd also need though is to check that if a new column is selected and shown that the option to add it is removed. I'd also build in a option to reset the table, hide all extra columns if someone makes a mistake/ or an option to turn on and off extra columns.

Comment: I was curious to find out how to solve this without Css, but that can be a solution. Thank you for your help S Jacks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work in my case using a PHP variable with the needed values I needed for the dropdown that I already had available in my script.

```
var shoes = <?php echo json_encode($data['shoes']);?>;
console.log(shoes);
0: {shoe_id: "3", brand_name: "Keen Koven WP"}
1: {shoe_id: "9", brand_name: "Keen Targhee Vent"}
2: {shoe_id: "5", brand_name: "Merrel MOAB Edge 2"}
3: {shoe_id: "1", brand_name: "New Balance 510v2"}
4: {shoe_id: "2", brand_name: "New Balance Trail Runners-All Terrain"}
5: {shoe_id: "6", brand_name: "Oboz Cirque Low"}
6: {shoe_id: "7", brand_name: "Oboz Sawtooth II Low"}
7: {shoe_id: "4", brand_name: "Oboz Sawtooth Low"}
8: {shoe_id: "8", brand_name: "Skechers Crossbar"}
```

Then I looped through the `shoes` variable and built up the string I needed for the dropdown values:

```
var shoes_result = '';
$.each(shoes, function(key, element) {
    shoes_result += '"'+element.shoe_id+'": "'+element.brand_name+'",';
});
shoes_result = shoes_result.substring(0,shoes_result.length-1); //strip trailing last comma.
console.log(shoes_result);
"3": "Keen Koven WP","9": "Keen Targhee Vent","5": "Merrel MOAB Edge 2","1": "New Balance 510v2","2": "New Balance Trail Runners-All Terrain","6": "Oboz Cirque Low","7": "Oboz Sawtooth II Low","4": "Oboz Sawtooth Low","8": "Skechers Crossbar"
```

Note: *Make sure and strip the trailing comma from the string*

Then concatenate the `shoes_result` string variable with `'{}'` that I need:

```
$('#walks-table').Tabledit({
  url: '<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/walks/update',
  columns: {
    identifier: [0, 'day_walked'],                   
    editable: [[1, 'cal_burned'], [2, 'miles_walked'], [3, 'duration'], [4, 'mph'], [5, 'shoes_worn', 'select', '{'+shoes_result+'}']]
  },
  editButton: <?php echo isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ? 'true' : 'false';?>,
  deleteButton: false,
  confirmButton: true,
});
```

**Note: I could not get this to work until I included the `'select`' type for this column**

Points of Note: I only have this working for the browser side and have not executed anything server-side (PHP) in my case so I don't know what kind of rough edges I may run into there. Also, I am a novice at best with jQuery so this solution might not be the best choice for implementation and/or optimisation.

Hope this helps and good luck!